Tkinter DoubleVar set empty value
How can I set an empty value in a Tkinter DoubleVar()?
I tried to do: my_var.set("") but when I try to check the value of my_var with my_var.get(), I receive the following error: _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

You can't, of course.  Use a StringVar instead, and apply float() to its value whenever you need it as a number (inside a try-except, most likely, to handle the case of it still being an empty value).

Thank you! I was hoping that something like None could do the job.
